# Creating a list of functions in java

Tags: java, testing, functions, list

I have a list of functions which need to be tested against a list of inputs to measure their relative performance.
I have already create a test function like below:

```
public static String testFunction(Function<int[], int[]> function , int[] input) {}
```

I have also generated a list of inputs to feed to each function. The code is still very repetitive as I have to call each function with `class::functionName` and each time I add a new function, it gets even worse! I was wondering if there is a way to create a list of functions so I can use a nested for loop to test all functions against all inputs! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, this is the best you can hope for.  For each new function, you must make an additional change to ensure that it gets called.  While you could pass an array of Functions to prevent setting up each individual call, you still need to alter the array with each successive function created, so it is ultimately no better.

Though if you're like me, you may want to categorize these functions so that you can have a single comprehensive list.  While it doesn't reduce the amount of changes you'll need to make to the code, this way I find is more organized.

```
public enum TestFunctions {
    BUBBLE_SORT(SortingAlgorithms::bubbleSort),
    QUICK_SORT(SortingAlgorithms::quickSort),
    MERGE_SORT(SortingAlgorithms::mergeSort),
    INSERTION_SORT(SortingAlgorithms::insertionSort);

    UnaryOperator<Integer[]> function;

    private TestFunctions(UnaryOperator<Integer[]> function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    public Integer[] call(Integer[] input) {
        return this.function.apply(input);
    }
}
```

Like this, your code can separate the function from where it's implemented.  You'd still need to add the new function here, but there's no getting around this unless you used reflection.  Though you could use reflection, I would strongly discourage you from doing so.  My experience is that it tends to create more problems than it solves in the long run.

Good luck!

Comment: thank you, I know I need to make changes every time, but it's way easier to add them to a list and have them be called automatically in a for loop rather than creating separate objects for it ... at the end of the day there are only about 12 algorithms and 6 data sets so I think I can do them manually XD

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a list of functions, that is very easy. You literally just need to create a `List` of `Function`s. Example:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

class Test {
  private static List<Function<int[], int[]>> functions = List.of(
      a -> new int[] { a[0] + a[1] },
      a -> new int[] { a[0] - a[1] }
  );

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (var f : functions) {
      System.out.println(f.apply(new int[] { 1, 2 })[0]);
    }
  }
}

// 3
// -1
```